# Insert character in Scala String

Tags: string, scala, scala-collections, scalaz, ropes

For any given `String`, for instance

```
val s = "abde"
```

how to insert a character `c: Char` at position 2, after `b` ?

**Update**

Which Scala collection to consider for multiple efficient insertions and deletions at random positions ? (Assuming that a `String` may be transformed into that collection.)

Comment: Get the substrings `[0,2)` and `[2,length)`, and then do `sub1 + c + sub2`

Comment: `String sub1 = s.substring(0,2)` gives you "ab"

Comment: Don't forget that strings are immutable

Comment: @enzyme generally speaking, if you're doing it a lot and you have long strings, [rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(computer_science)) is the right data structure. IIRC, Scala has no such thing in standard library, though.

Comment: @om-nom-nom thanks! looks like the way to go... looking for Scala rope implementations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rope data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29) proves a valid alternative to `String` and `StringBuffer` for heavy manipulation in (very) large strings, especially in regard to insertions and deletions.

[Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) includes `class Rope[A]` (see [API](http://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/scalaz-2.10-7.0.1/doc/index.html#scalaz.Rope) and [Rope.scala](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.0.1/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Rope.scala)) and `class WrappedRope[A]` (see [API](http://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/scalaz-2.10-7.0.1/doc/index.html#scalaz.WrappedRope)) with a plethora of operations on rope strings.

Implementations in Java include http://ahmadsoft.org/ropes/. A benchmarking study for this Java implementation may be found at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ropes/ .

A publication on ropes as an alternative to strings may be found at http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.9450&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 14):

We can use the [`patch`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html#patch(from:Int,other:String,replaced:Int):String) method on `String`s in order to insert a `String` at a specific index:

```
"abde".patch(2, "c", 0)
// "abcde"
```

This:

- drops `0` (third parameter) elements at index `2`
- inserts `"c"` at index `2`

which in other words means `patching 0 elements at index 2 with the string "c"`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
val (fst, snd) = s.splitAt(2)
fst + 'c' + snd
```

Comment: not sure whether `Vector`s suit for your requirement. check performance characteristics in [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html)